# Xcode 10 warning: ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES requested with multiple ARCHS and no run destination to provide an active architecture

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

In Xcode when the run destination is set to "Generic iOS device" and using the recommended setting `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES` for debug configuration, when building the warning `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES requested with multiple ARCHS and no run destination to provide an active architecture` is produced. This makes sense as no run destination is selected, but it's an annoying warning (it's produced for every build target dependency). However if `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` is set to `NO` then you get recommended project changes to set it to `YES` for debug configuration. Is there a way to avoid this warning when the run destination is set to "Generic iOS device"?

Comment: Any update on this issue... getting same